# Breaking down sawdust pellets causing heat

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-potential

We just discovered that pellets (sawdust, animal feed, organic constituents) when re-hydrated give off heat.  We understand this at molecular levels but are having a hard time sussing this out at a macro level.  Do these pellets (pellet stove sawdust type in particular) absorb energy when compressed to release it when water is added and they break down into the particles they were made from?

Comment: This is a physics question. You can read about adsorption enthalpy.

Answer (score 0):

Nono. What you're assuming is wrong. 
Hydration enthalpy is what is behind the scene, and its macro because it's Thermodynamics. Whenever you hydrate the sawdust particles, hydration enthalpy is given off which is what you've observed.